# Concurrent Requests and Session State in ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, session-state

I am keeping track of the number of times a client calls a particular controller action in a single session. The requirement is to limit the total number of requests to the action method to some value (e.g. 10). If the client makes more than 10 request, I reject the request with 403 Forbidden.

The action method (simplified) looks like below:

```
private readonly static object _lockObj = new();

public IActionResult Subscribe()
{
        lock(_lockObj){ //lockObj is declared in the controller as private static readonly lockObj = new ();    
            int? subscriptionCount = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("SubscriptionCount");

            if (subscriptionCount == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("SubscriptionCount", 1);
            }
            else
            {
                if (subscriptionCount > 10)
                {
                    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden, {"Result":"Max subscriptions per user/session reached"});
                }else{
                    subscriptionCount++;
                    HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("SubscriptionCount", subscriptionCount.Value);
                    Console.Writeline($"SubscriptionCount={subscriptionCount}");
                    return Ok({"Result": "Created"});
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I have used lock to synchronize access in action method but still the count goes haywire when a client makes concurrent requests. The above works as expected if the client makes the requests serially.

Client sending concurrent requests:

```
function sendParallelRequests(){
    const host = "localhost:5001";
    const options = {
          method: "POST",          
          credentials: "include",          
    };
    const reqs = [];
    for(let i=0;i < 15;i++){
         reqs.push(fetch(`http://${host}/subscription`, options).then((res) => res.json()));
    }
    const allData = Promise.all(reqs);
    allData.then((res) => console.log(res));       
}
```

When the above client is run, I can see multiple requests having access to the same session value i.e. the Console.Writeline() prints the same value multiple times.

The following client sends requests serially and this works as expected.

```
async function sendSerialRequests(){
    const host = "localhost:5001";
    const options = {
          method: "POST",          
          credentials: "include",          
    };  
    for(let i=0;i < 15;i++){
        const res = await fetch(`http://${host}/subscription`, options);
        console.log(await res.json());
    }
}
```

Note: In both the above cases, the session id is same.

Comment: From a logical point of view: how do you identify distinct clients?

Comment: Translation - you want to implement rate limiting per client. You can't do it like this. By the time you reach `HttpContext.Session` it's too late. There are many articles that explain how to create rate limiting middleware [like this one](https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-web-api-rate-limiting/), ready made packages like [this one](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit). .NET 7 will come with built-in [rate limiting middleware](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-rate-limiting-for-dotnet/). The correct response is 429 with specific headers

Comment: As for *storage*, `Session` is the wrong place. A session is retrieved *after* a requests is already being processed. A better place to store that data is in-memory or distributed cache

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is not exactly rate limiting in that sense. I want to ensure a client in a session's lifetime (could be hours/days) cannot create more than 10 subscriptions. This is not a throttling requirement either.

Comment: @Marco. Client here is synonymous with a unique session

Comment: That's not what you asked in the question. In that case you have to *queue* the requests to another service (might just be a singleton service), have *it* process the requests and respond. You could also use a database. Depending on the database you use you could write a *single* `UPDATE` call that increments if it's below limit and returns the new value, eg `UPDATE Subscriptions SET Count=Count+1 OUTPUT inserted.Count WHERE UserID=@id and Count<10` in SQL Server. PostgreSQL uses `RETURNING` to do the same

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Apologize if it wasn't clear in my question. Let us say I just need to count the number of a requests to a particular controller action per session id. Do you still think session is not right place for holding this counter?

Comment: Is `_lockObj` decorated with `[ThreadStatic]` attribute?

Comment: I mostly agree with @PanagiotisKanavos here, but let's say you really don't want to rate-limit, you want the logic, but for another purpose.  Are you aware that a customer can simply open a different browser and get 10 more subscriptions?  This is because a session is identified by an ID in a cookie.  Different browser, different cookie store.  Your approach seems to be inherently faulty from the start.  You need a thread-safe dictionary or something even fancier.

Comment: @CùĐứcHiếu Updated the question

Comment: @JoséRamírez It is absolutely fine if the user opens another browser and is allowed to create 10 more. That is actually the requirement.

Comment: If that's the case, then go for this.  The problem here seems that each HTTP request gets a **copy** of the session data.  This copy of the data is performed **before** your lock, so locking accomplishes nothing.  I tried to find documentation that supports my suspicions but could not find.  Use a synchronized dictionary instead of Session.  Store the dictionary key in session.  Then this will work.

Comment: Your JS code calls `subscription` but the action is called `Subscribe`. Are you sure you're calling the correct method?

Comment: @JoséRamírez That is my suspicion as well but I am unable to find any source which can confirm this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The action is decorated as [Route("subscription")]. I am very sure the action is called. I have tried debugging with breakpoints and the breakpoints get the hit.

Comment: @JoséRamírez I have actually solved the issue using a dictionary for now as you mention. The reason I asked this question is to understand the underlying behaviour of session data.